# Override QueryInterface using ATL

Tags: c++, atl

Is it possible to provide an implementation to QueryInterface for classes using `ATL`?

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CConcrete) // Defines _InternalQueryInterface
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IInterface)
END_COM_MAP() // Defines QueryInterface as a pure virtual function which
              // is overridden in CComObject<CConcrete>
```

I'm overriding for mocking purposes, allowing a user to simulate a `QueryInterface` failure. I would like to maintain the default `ATL` QueryInterface functionality when not being explicitly configured.

The call stack looks like this:

```
CComObjectRootBase::InternalQueryInterface
CConcrete::_InternalQueryInterface // BEGIN_COM_MAP
CComObject<CConcrete>::QueryInterface // Override of QI from END_COM_MAP
```

Comment: You can simulate missing interface using [`COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_NOINTERFACE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6ba4c4b.aspx) and you can certainly override it in other ways. Using this documented macro is perhaps the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a new version of `BEGIN_COM_MAP` that doesn't include an implementation for `_InternalQueryInterface`. I then put my mocking code in there, and forwarded non-mocked calls to `InternalQueryInterface`.